If condition in Email Template not working
I have added one if condition to email template but it is not working.
{IF({{{Custom__c.is_custom_true__c}}}, 'Yes', 'No')}
Output:
IF(1, 'Yes', 'No')
Expected Output:
Yes
Also if I try to write if statement like this:
{!IF(Custom__c.is_custom_true__c, "Yes", "No")}
it shows this error:

This template doesn’t support SML merge fields. Use the merge field picker to replace merge fields starting with "{!".: HTML Value


read the conditional HML doc carefully: Conditional statements create one-to-one replacements for empty field values, but they don’t evaluate fields for the type of data they contain. For example, you display certain content based on whether a prospect has data for their City field, but not based on whether their city is San Francisco. - what you want to do is not supported this way

You can change the field type from checkbox to dropdown to make it work.

You can check the how if condition works in the Lightning Email Template.
Use HML Conditional Merge Fields
For example:
{{#if Custom__c.is_custom_true__c}}
Yes
{{else}}
No
{{/if}}

Alternative Approach: You can create a formula field on the object that evaluates the condition and returns the desired text.
For example, create a formula field Formatted_Value__c on Custom__c with the formula:
IF(Custom__c.is_custom_true__c, "Yes", "No")
Then, use this formula field in your email template:
{{Custom__c.Formatted_Value__c}}

{{#if Custom__c.is_custom_true__c}}
Yes
{{else}}
No
{{/if}}
This is only showing yes, even when checkbox is unchecked.

@SFDCSalesforce, Can you please try the alternative approach?

I don't want to create an additional formula field for all the checkboxes as I have many fields like this with same requirement.

@SFDCSalesforce, Then you can use the classic email template instead of Lightning.

the HML conditional expression doc you reference only supports testing whether a value is null (equivalent to BLANKVALUE formula function)
